# Two functions in a single query using PHP, MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

```
$query = "SELECT email_address FROM users where email_address NOT IN (SELECT email_address FROM phone_mac_details)";

$query = "SELECT email_address FROM users where account_id=".$_SESSION['admin_id'];
```

Above are two queries for filtering data.
first one is to filter users email and displaying available users to allot work.
second one is to filter clients after login.

So I want to display the particular client's available users which is not in (select email_address FROM phone_mac_details). For that I need to combine both the queries.
Now it is displaying either of one query.
Please give me syntax to combine two queries.

Comment: use union all to combine both queries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this query

```
$query = "SELECT email_address FROM users WHERE account_id=" . $_SESSION['admin_id'] . " AND email_address NOT IN (SELECT email_address FROM phone_mac_details)";
```

Comment: It is giving syntax error.can you please check this?                                       $query =  "SELECT email_address FROM users WHERE account_id=" . $_SESSION['admin_id'] . " AND email_address NOT IN (SELECT email_address FROM phone_mac_details)

Comment: I got the result. It is  $query = "SELECT email_address FROM users WHERE account_id=" . $_SESSION['admin_id'] . " AND email_address NOT IN (SELECT email_address FROM phone_mac_details)";                   Thanks for the help.

Comment: @ShriSuresh please don't bully people into accepting an answer.